# How to prove $A \succeq B \Leftrightarrow AB=B$ for orthogonal projectors $A, B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, projection-matrices, projection

For orthogonal projection matrices $A, B \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, we have that

- $A^\top = A$ and $A^2 = A$
- $B^\top = B$ and $B^2 = B$

where $A^\top$ is the transpose of $A$, and $A \succeq B $ says that $A-B$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

I would like to prove the following proposition

$$A \succeq B \Leftrightarrow AB = B$$

For showing $A \succeq B \Rightarrow AB = B$, we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
A-B \succeq 0 &\Rightarrow x^\top (A-B)x \ge 0 \; \forall x \\
&\Rightarrow y^\top(I-A)^\top(A-B)(I-A)y \ge 0 \; \text{for } x = (I-A)y \; \forall y\\
&\Rightarrow y^\top(I-A)^\top B(I-A)y \le 0 \; \forall y \; \text{ as } A(I-A)=0 \\
&\Rightarrow y^\top(I-A)^\top B(I-A)y = 0 \; \forall y \; \text{ as } B \succeq 0\\
&\Rightarrow y^\top(I-A)^\top B^\top B(I-A)y = 0 \; \forall y \; \text{ as } B=B^2=B^\top B \\
&\Rightarrow B(I-A) = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow A^\top B^\top = B^\top \\
&\Rightarrow AB = B
\end{aligned}
$$

Not sure how to show $A-B\succeq 0 \Leftarrow AB = B$.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: You are better to define the symbols and state the question in the form of a proposition. For example, the symbol $\succeq$ is not a universally accepted. It is better to define it. Moreover, I remember that the proposition continues to hold for bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space. Are your projection operators acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$, or a general Hilbert space?

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I see there can be ambiguity. I updated  with some notation now.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\Leftarrow$ direction: Suppose that $AB=B$. Observe that $BA=B^{T}A^{T}=(AB)^{T}=B^{T}=B=AB$.
That is, $A$ and B commutes. Also, $(I-B)^{2}=I-B$. Let $x$ be
an arbitrary vector. Consider 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \langle(A-B)x,x\rangle\\
 & = & \langle A(I-B)x,x\rangle\\
 & = & \langle A(I-B)^{2}x,x\rangle\\
 & = & \langle(I-B)A(I-B)x,x\rangle\\
 & = & \langle A(I-B)x,(I-B)^{T}x\rangle\\
 & = & \langle A(I-B)x,(I-B)x\rangle\\
 & \geq & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
(In the above, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual inner
product.) Obviously $A-B$ is symmetric. Hence, $A-B$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: How did you get the last inequality ?

Comment: Every projection is positive semi-definite. For, let $A$ be a projection, i.e., $A^T=A$ and $A^2=A$. Let $x$ be a vector, then $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle AAx,x\rangle = \langle Ax,A^Tx\rangle =\langle Ax,Ax\rangle \geq 0$.